# Table view is misplaced on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, view

I have a problem with how my TableView is displayed, here is a picture of it:

[image]
Now this TableView is inside view, here is screenshot from xcode:
[image]

The thing is there are two views and both of them have a TableView.
TableView number 1 works as expected, but second tableview (the one in the first picture) is misplaced even though both views have exactly the same constrains (just added them again, to make sure).

So why this happens? What else, besides views constrains I can check?

Comment: hey men no need to use for second tableview..just refresh the tableview with different data..it will good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the relevant view controllers, change the options for **Adjust Scroll View Insets** and **Under Top Bars**. I usually want them both *on*.

[image]